# python 2.7 re.MULTILINE troubles

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pycurl

I am new to python and I have been trying to change my php regex into python but I have run into some problems with this multiline thing. I have been up and down the internet for the past couple days and I can't seem to make sense of it, if someone could help that would be great. Here is the regex I have made:

```
mlsTagRegex = re.compile("<td\swidth=\"13%\"\sclass=\"TopHeader\">(.*?)</td>", re.MULTILINE)
tdTags = mlsTagRegex.findall(output.getvalue())
print tdTags
```

Here is the HTML I would like it to find:

```
<td width="13%" class="TopHeader">

   <span class="red">I WANT THIS PART</span>

</td>
```

and it just gives me an empty array. I'm pretty sure what I am missing is probably fairly simple but like I said I am new to python so if anyone could help? Thanks!

p.s.: the output in findall is what pycurl is outputting and that part of the html is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use re.DOTALL,so the '.' character will match any character,including the newline.

Comment: OMG thank you so much. I knew it was going to be something simple like that!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) to make `.` match newline characters:

```
mlsTagRegex = re.compile(r'<td width="13%" class="TopHeader">(.*?)</td>', re.DOTALL)
```

But really you should avoid using regex for parsing html, use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/) instead.

Comment: @zeekay: you're correct in that regular expressions are not good for matching arbitrary HTML, but this seems to be one of the simple cases where regexps will work sufficiently well.

Comment: I would disagree, this is an extremely fragile regex expression that will break if *any* type of change is made to the generated HTML.